# Why the delete function is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Following is a part of my to-do list application. The delete function is not working properly

```
function deleteTodoItem(e, item) {
  $(item).parent().remove();
};

$(function() {
  $("#MyList").on('click', '.todo-item-delete', function(e) {

    var item = this;
    deleteTodoItem(e, item)
  })
});
```

Comment: can post the html part? a snippet of it would be best.. also, your indentation...

Answer (score 0):

```
function deleteTodoItem(elem) {
  elem.parent().remove();
};

$(function() {
  $("#MyList").on('click', '.todo-item-delete', function() {


    deleteTodoItem($(this))
  })
});
```

short code

```
$(function() {
      $("#MyList").on('click', '.todo-item-delete', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
      })
    });
```